# How to create TSD for a module with default export?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a TSD for [fscreen.js](https://github.com/rafrex/fscreen/blob/master/src/index.js) but I'm struggling with the fact it's a default export.

Based on the guidance on the [Typescript website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html), it says:

> If your module is not callable or constructable, use the module.d.ts
>   file.

As this is the case, I'm using the [module.d.ts template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html).

So the index.d.ts file looks like:

```
export function requestFullscreen(element: any): void;
export function requestFullscreenFunction(element: any): () => void;
export function exitFullscreen();
export function addEventListener(type: string, handler: () => void, options: any): void;
export var fullscreenEnabled: boolean;
export var fullscreenElement: any;
export var onfullscreenchange: (event: any) => void;
export var onfullscreenerror: (event: any) => void;
```

Consuming it:

```
import * as fscreen from 'fscreen';
```

and it compiles fine. However, when I check the actual value of fscreen at runtime it looks like:

[image: console info]

I've also searched SO for other questions, some other posts suggests I have to define it in my TSD as:

```
export default class fscreen {
  fullscreenElement: any;
  ...
}
```

But then it doesn't compile and it seems to think `fscreen` is a function?
[image]

I've also tried this:

```
declare class fscreen {
  fullscreenElement: any;
  fullscreenEnabled: any;
  exitFullscreen: any;
  requestFullscreen: any;  
}
export = fscreen;
```

Importing like this:

```
import fscreen = require('fscreen');
```

But then I get the problem that again it seems to think it's a function, and it throws these exceptions:

```
TS2339: Property 'requestFullscreen' does not exist on type 'typeof fscreen'.
```

It feels like I'm almost there. Have wasted so much time on this already and I'm stuck. So, how can I modify my TSD such that it properly defines the default export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consume it with `import fscreen from 'fscreen'` then the following will work in a `*.d.ts` file.

```js
/**
 * Associate this type declaration file with the `fscreen` module.
 */
declare module 'fscreen' {

    /**
     * Declare a type for an object with methods and properties.
     */
    type FScreen = {
        requestFullScreen: (element: unknown) => unknown;
        requestFullScreenFunction: (element: unknown) => unknown;
        exitFullScreen: unknown;
        fullscreenPseudoClass: unknown;
        // other code omitted
    };

    /**
     * Declare an object that implements that type.
     */
    const fscreen: FScreen;

    /**
     * Default export that object.
     */
    export default fscreen;
}
```

Here is the result on my computer:

[image]

For brevity, I only partly implemented the type, and I used `unknown` because I am not familiar with `fscreen`.

Also, in case it might help, here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Shaun!!! That indeed works! I've spent all morning on this. default exports are not documented well on the Typescript website, perhaps a good addition.